# Cron in my custom module is not running

Tags: magento2.3, magento-cron

I have created a cron group as below,

cron_groups.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * path:
 * magento_home/app/code/vendor/module/etc/cron_groups.xml
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="sync_api">
        <schedule_generate_every>1</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>4</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>2</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
        <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
    </group>
</config>
```

And my crontab.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">

<group id="sync_api">

    <job name="custom_cronjob" instance="Ucs\Api\Sync\Test" method="execute">

        <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>

    </job>

</group>

</config>
```

After adding this, I executed, `upgrade`, `compile`, `cache:clean` commands, Once it is done,

I've run a command as `php bin:magento cron:run`

Once all done, I checked `cron_schedule` and have found my next cron is not at all scheduled.

Also, in the admin `stores->configuration->advance->cron` tab I can see my `sync_api` tab. I have configured `Generate Schedules Every` as 1.

After all these tries, nothing works.

** Edit **

Obviously, I did cron run by group,
[image: Cron Run]

Even after doing that I haven't found the scheduler in `cron_schedule` table.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run your cron group via below code:

```
php bin/magento cron:run --group="sync_api"
```

Also before do this,please clear the cache.

***Please follow the below articles for setup custom crontab group at magento 2***

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-ref.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html

Comment: Yes, I did that too. Refer my updated question.

Comment: I fixed the issue. instance attribute should be `instance="Ucs\Api\Controller\Sync\Test"` instead of `instance="Ucs\Api\Sync\Test"`. Anyway thanks for your attention. +1

Comment: @Butterfly my cron is also not working don't know why while its instance is `Vender/Module/Cron/Test` when I tried it for first time it was working but after making bit of changing it stop working.

Comment: @AsadKhan if you think, your latest changes have affected, refer the `setup_cron` table and see what is the error magento has captured. Also, refer your log files too

Comment: @Amit Bera, In my case, cron is only working when I run the command manually. Why its not running automatically? Please guide